# Node.js prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

Trying to wrap my mind around prototypes in Javascript, specifically Node.js, with a simple test.

```
function Lint() {
    this.input = 'foo';
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

Lint.prototype.dirs = function (dirs) {
    _.each(dirs, this.files);
}

Lint.prototype.files = function (dir) {
    console.log(this.input); // trying to get 'foo', returns undefined
}

var lint = new Lint();

lint.dirs(['js', 'js/views']);
```

`Lint.prototype.files` logs undefined because `this` isn't referring to the instance of Lint. What am I missing here?

The only solution I can think of, that works, is passing around the initial `this` from `Lint.prototype.dirs` to each other function. I'm pretty sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to the `lint` object, but you're not passing the `Lint` object to `_.each`. You're detaching the function from the object and passing that.

You can bind the context of a function to the desired value using `Function.prototype.bind`...

```
_.each(dirs, this.files.bind(this));
```

Or, you could keep a reference to the `this` value, and pass an anonymous function to `_.each`...

```
var this_lint = this;

_.each(dirs, function(v) {
    this_lint.files(v);
}
```

Comment: @alex: That's my thing now. All my answers are CW, so feel free to pitch in if you'd like. ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much!
Interestingly enough, why does this variation return false?
`var this_lint = this;`
`_.each(dirs, this_lint.files);`

Comment: @wayne: In that case, you're really doing the same thing as you were in your original code. You're just passing the `.files` function to the `_.each`. The `this_lint` does not stay with the function when you pass it. That's where `.bind` is handy. It creates a new function with the first argument given to `.bind` set as the `this` value of the new function.